# How can I get the table like this?

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I have three tables in my database - campaign, app, revenue.

**Campaign:**

```
 id | name
----+------
  1 | Gis1
  2 | Gis2
  3 | Gis3
```

**App:**

```
 app_id |   name    | campaign_id
--------+-----------+-------------
      1 | Paino     |           1
      2 | Guitar    |           1
      3 | DrumPads  |           1
      4 | Karaoke   |           2
      5 | Metronome |           3
```

**Revenue:**

```
    date    | app_id |      revenue      
------------+--------+-------------------
 2018-01-01 |      3 |   78.538551844269 
 2018-01-01 |      4 |  38.8709466245191 
 2018-01-01 |      2 |  35.5413845637373 
 2018-01-01 |      1 |  28.6825649309465 
 2018-01-01 |      5 |  6.33375584214843 
 2018-01-02 |      4 |   75.162254483704 
 2018-01-02 |      1 |  73.2370500155917 
 2018-01-02 |      5 |  70.4319678991422 
 2018-01-02 |      2 |  61.6702865774691 
 2018-01-02 |      3 |  11.7512900955221 
 2018-01-03 |      3 |  96.3792688491068 
 2018-01-03 |      4 |  84.3478274916822 
 2018-01-03 |      2 |  78.6001262071822 
 2018-01-03 |      5 |  13.8776103129058 
 2018-01-03 |      1 |  1.68915693074764 
 2018-01-04 |      5 |  99.4360222634511 
 2018-01-04 |      4 |  90.1921250023309 
 2018-01-04 |      3 |  16.5334091972016 
 2018-01-04 |      2 |  10.5714115940407 
 2018-01-04 |      1 |  1.35598296965985 
 2018-01-05 |      5 |  80.2475503409425 
 2018-01-05 |      4 |  38.9817245329402 
 2018-01-05 |      2 |   34.409188396027 
 2018-01-05 |      3 |  20.4833489416672 
 2018-01-05 |      1 |  2.61399153047812 
 2018-01-06 |      3 |  87.8649452536831 
 2018-01-06 |      1 |  74.4561480870284 
 2018-01-06 |      5 |  21.6574319699022 
 2018-01-06 |      2 |  4.87542333346478 
 2018-01-06 |      4 |  1.14697005074565 
 2018-01-07 |      1 |  87.9779788101898 
 2018-01-07 |      4 |  77.7294346579956 
 2018-01-07 |      3 |  59.3464731223967 
 2018-01-07 |      2 |    40.95148445392 
 2018-01-07 |      5 |  5.06283105895021 
 2018-01-08 |      1 |  96.2285605244126 
 2018-01-08 |      2 |    95.07328406998 
 2018-01-08 |      3 |  92.0486340327792 
 2018-01-08 |      4 |   85.379685234924 
 2018-01-08 |      5 |  9.78507570055686 
 2018-01-09 |      1 |  62.8192365909115 
 2018-01-09 |      4 |  62.0064597273823 
 2018-01-09 |      5 |  48.0621315020228 
 2018-01-09 |      3 |  29.7547369619939 
 2018-01-09 |      2 |  12.2752425067087 
 2018-01-10 |      2 |  81.0502551311092 
 2018-01-10 |      3 |  48.9698039641851 
 2018-01-10 |      1 |  17.5580143188766 
 2018-01-10 |      5 |   16.961404890828 
 2018-01-10 |      4 |  15.8832169199418 
 2018-01-11 |      2 |  77.6197753309208 
 2018-01-11 |      4 |  37.7590440824396 
 2018-01-11 |      1 |   28.964817136957 
 2018-01-11 |      3 |   28.706793080089 
 2018-01-11 |      5 |  26.9639842717711 
 2018-01-12 |      3 |  87.2789863299996 
 2018-01-12 |      1 |  78.8013559572292 
 2018-01-12 |      4 |  57.4583081599463 
 2018-01-12 |      5 |  48.0822281547709 
 2018-01-12 |      2 | 0.839615458734033 
 2018-01-13 |      3 |  69.8766551973526 
 2018-01-13 |      2 |  58.3078275325981 
 2018-01-13 |      5 |  21.8336755576109 
 2018-01-13 |      4 |   11.370240413885 
 2018-01-13 |      1 |  1.86340769095961 
 2018-01-14 |      5 |  92.6937944833375 
 2018-01-14 |      4 |  87.4130741995654 
 2018-01-14 |      3 |  72.2022209237481 
 2018-01-14 |      1 |   17.323222911245 
 2018-01-14 |      2 |  14.1322298298443 
 2018-01-15 |      2 |  90.8789341373927 
 2018-01-15 |      4 |    74.78605271702 
 2018-01-15 |      1 |   65.674207749016 
 2018-01-15 |      5 |  33.0848315520449 
 2018-01-15 |      3 |  19.7583865950811 
 2018-01-16 |      5 |  66.2050914825085 
 2018-01-16 |      4 |  34.6843542862023 
 2018-01-16 |      1 |  29.5897929780101 
 2018-01-16 |      2 |  15.0023649485883 
 2018-01-16 |      3 |  7.54663420658891 
 2018-01-17 |      2 |  83.3703723270077 
 2018-01-17 |      3 |   61.088943523605 
 2018-01-17 |      4 |  46.5194411862903 
 2018-01-17 |      5 |   46.462239550764 
 2018-01-17 |      1 |  16.1838123321874 
 2018-01-18 |      5 |  78.0041560412725 
 2018-01-18 |      4 |  30.3052500891844 
 2018-01-18 |      2 |  29.8116578069311 
 2018-01-18 |      3 |  5.80476470204397 
 2018-01-18 |      1 |  2.28775040131831 
 2018-01-19 |      5 |  94.0447243349086 
 2018-01-19 |      2 |  93.2593723776554 
 2018-01-19 |      3 |  86.2968057525727 
 2018-01-19 |      1 |  42.7138322733396 
 2018-01-19 |      4 |  22.1327564577787 
 2018-01-20 |      3 |  98.8579713044872 
 2018-01-20 |      5 |  64.8200087378497 
 2018-01-20 |      4 |  64.7727513652878 
 2018-01-20 |      2 |  39.2598249004273 
 2018-01-20 |      1 |  25.6178488851919 
 2018-01-21 |      3 |  84.4040426309011 
 2018-01-21 |      1 |  52.0713063443698 
 2018-01-21 |      5 |  41.7424199787255 
 2018-01-21 |      4 |  35.3389400530059 
 2018-01-21 |      2 |   28.350741474429 
 2018-01-22 |      2 |  96.8320321290855 
 2018-01-22 |      3 |  74.0004402752697 
 2018-01-22 |      1 |  72.5235460636752 
 2018-01-22 |      5 |   53.607618058446 
 2018-01-22 |      4 |  41.3008316635055 
 2018-01-23 |      2 |  66.6286214457232 
 2018-01-23 |      3 |  54.1626139019933 
 2018-01-23 |      5 |  52.5239485716162 
 2018-01-23 |      4 |  25.7367743326983 
 2018-01-23 |      1 |  6.46491466744874 
 2018-01-24 |      2 |  83.5308430627458 
 2018-01-24 |      1 |  68.6328785122374 
 2018-01-24 |      4 |  55.6973785257225 
 2018-01-24 |      3 |  46.0264499615527 
 2018-01-24 |      5 |  16.4651600203735 
 2018-01-25 |      4 |  80.9564163429763 
 2018-01-25 |      5 |  62.5899942406707 
 2018-01-25 |      1 |  59.0336831992662 
 2018-01-25 |      2 |  46.4030509765701 
 2018-01-25 |      3 |  22.6888680448289 
 2018-01-26 |      4 |  76.5099290710172 
 2018-01-26 |      3 |   53.933127563048 
 2018-01-26 |      5 |  49.5466520893498 
 2018-01-26 |      2 |  45.1699294234721 
 2018-01-26 |      1 |  21.3764512981173 
 2018-01-27 |      1 |  90.5434132585012 
 2018-01-27 |      4 |  67.0016445981484 
 2018-01-27 |      3 |  11.2431627841556 
 2018-01-27 |      2 |  5.39719616685773 
 2018-01-27 |      5 |  2.11776835627748 
 2018-01-28 |      2 |  53.3541751891504 
 2018-01-28 |      1 |  32.9596394913923 
 2018-01-28 |      3 |  21.1895497351378 
 2018-01-28 |      4 |  16.2897762555689 
 2018-01-28 |      5 |  5.34709359321544 
 2018-01-29 |      1 |  64.5439256676011 
 2018-01-29 |      2 |  15.9776125576869 
 2018-01-29 |      4 |  11.0105036902667 
 2018-01-29 |      3 |  2.16601788703412 
 2018-01-29 |      5 | 0.555523083910259 
 2018-01-30 |      4 |  94.7839147312857 
 2018-01-30 |      5 |  72.6621727991897 
 2018-01-30 |      3 |   70.124043314061 
 2018-01-30 |      2 |  34.5961079425723 
 2018-01-30 |      1 |  33.2888204556319 
 2018-01-31 |      3 |  77.7231288650421 
 2018-01-31 |      1 |  56.8044673174345 
 2018-01-31 |      4 |  43.5046513642636 
 2018-01-31 |      5 |  41.5792942791069 
 2018-01-31 |      2 |  25.5788387345906 
 2018-02-01 |      3 |  95.2107725320766 
 2018-02-01 |      4 |  86.3486448391141 
 2018-02-01 |      5 |  78.3239590582078 
 2018-02-01 |      2 |  39.1536975881585 
 2018-02-01 |      1 |  36.0675078797763 
 2018-02-02 |      5 |  97.8803713050822 
 2018-02-02 |      1 |  79.4247662701352 
 2018-02-02 |      2 |  26.3779061699958 
 2018-02-02 |      3 |  22.4354942949645 
 2018-02-02 |      4 |  13.2603534317112 
 2018-02-03 |      3 |  96.1323726327063 
 2018-02-03 |      5 |  59.6632595622737 
 2018-02-03 |      1 |   27.389807545151 
 2018-02-03 |      2 |  7.76389782111102 
 2018-02-03 |      4 | 0.969840948318645 
 2018-02-04 |      3 |  75.3978559173567 
 2018-02-04 |      5 |  49.3882938530803 
 2018-02-04 |      2 |  39.1100010374179 
 2018-02-04 |      4 |  35.8242148224422 
 2018-02-04 |      1 |  7.23734382101905 
 2018-02-05 |      4 |  75.3672510776635 
 2018-02-05 |      5 |  64.5369740371526 
 2018-02-05 |      3 |  51.5082265591993 
 2018-02-05 |      1 |  32.3788448578061 
 2018-02-05 |      2 |  21.4472612365463 
 2018-02-06 |      3 |  53.4502002775965 
 2018-02-06 |      2 |  53.0717656757934 
 2018-02-06 |      1 |  40.8672220798649 
 2018-02-06 |      4 |   37.839976598642 
 2018-02-06 |      5 |  9.12020377129901 
 2018-02-07 |      5 |  97.4855788083418 
 2018-02-07 |      4 |  97.4608054761709 
 2018-02-07 |      1 |  95.6723225551752 
 2018-02-07 |      3 |  87.9714358507064 
 2018-02-07 |      2 |  38.2405435002047 
 2018-02-08 |      4 |  82.9874314133669 
 2018-02-08 |      5 |  82.6651133226406 
 2018-02-08 |      1 |  69.3052440890685 
 2018-02-08 |      2 |  51.1343060185741 
 2018-02-08 |      3 |  25.5081553094595 
 2018-02-09 |      2 |  77.6589355538231 
 2018-02-09 |      5 |  74.7649757096248 
 2018-02-09 |      4 |  74.0052834670764 
 2018-02-09 |      1 |    37.58471748555 
 2018-02-09 |      3 |  9.52726961562965 
 2018-02-10 |      4 |  63.5114625028904 
 2018-02-10 |      1 |  57.6003561091767 
 2018-02-10 |      3 |  33.8354238124814 
 2018-02-10 |      5 |   24.755497452165 
 2018-02-10 |      2 |  6.09719410861046 
 2018-02-11 |      3 |  99.3200679204704 
 2018-02-11 |      4 |   92.787953262445 
 2018-02-11 |      2 |  75.7916875546417 
 2018-02-11 |      1 |  74.1264023056354 
 2018-02-11 |      5 |  39.0543105010909 
 2018-02-12 |      4 |  73.9016911300489 
 2018-02-12 |      2 |  36.8834180654883 
 2018-02-12 |      3 |   30.824684325787 
 2018-02-12 |      5 |  29.1559120548307 
 2018-02-12 |      1 |  10.1162943083399 
 2018-02-13 |      1 |  88.0975197801571 
 2018-02-13 |      3 |  73.3753659668181 
 2018-02-13 |      4 |  63.0762892472857 
 2018-02-13 |      5 |  35.8151357458788 
 2018-02-13 |      2 |  13.4014942840453 
 2018-02-14 |      1 |  94.8739671484573 
 2018-02-14 |      2 |  91.6415916160249 
 2018-02-14 |      5 |  66.2281593912018 
 2018-02-14 |      4 |    42.94700050317 
 2018-02-14 |      3 |  26.5246491333787 
 2018-02-15 |      2 |  98.7486846642082 
 2018-02-15 |      5 |  69.6182587287506 
 2018-02-15 |      3 |  44.6821718318301 
 2018-02-15 |      4 |  21.9568740682904 
 2018-02-15 |      1 |   15.374522578894 
 2018-02-16 |      2 |  94.3365941896695 
 2018-02-16 |      1 |   53.269122319394 
 2018-02-16 |      3 |  39.6046035126169 
 2018-02-16 |      4 |   37.622514510779 
 2018-02-16 |      5 |  31.3474270053205 
 2018-02-17 |      3 |  70.0631248181593 
 2018-02-17 |      5 |  50.1262781461011 
 2018-02-17 |      2 |  43.9279952731992 
 2018-02-17 |      1 |  28.2582849814117 
 2018-02-17 |      4 |  21.0913544631149 
 2018-02-18 |      3 |  74.8909778287795 
 2018-02-18 |      2 |  74.2363801582102 
 2018-02-18 |      5 |  72.4878600270842 
 2018-02-18 |      1 |  25.6855071233935 
 2018-02-18 |      4 |  0.37039199763309 
 2018-02-19 |      3 |  83.3856751613489 
 2018-02-19 |      5 |  46.4974932948942 
 2018-02-19 |      2 |  6.43301299768522 
 2018-02-19 |      4 |  4.81320557633388 
 2018-02-19 |      1 |  2.15515010060456 
 2018-02-20 |      4 |  81.4230771798843 
 2018-02-20 |      5 |  57.7265346180577 
 2018-02-20 |      1 |  56.2984247130064 
 2018-02-20 |      2 |  49.0169450043801 
 2018-02-20 |      3 |  46.5627217436774 
 2018-02-21 |      1 |  96.5297614033189 
 2018-02-21 |      5 |  96.2494094090932 
 2018-02-21 |      3 |  31.3462847216426 
 2018-02-21 |      4 |  23.2941891242544 
 2018-02-21 |      2 |  19.9083254355315 
 2018-02-22 |      1 |  79.0770313884165 
 2018-02-22 |      2 |  64.9973229306064 
 2018-02-22 |      3 |  55.3855288854335 
 2018-02-22 |      4 |   53.814505037514 
 2018-02-22 |      5 |   24.401256997123 
 2018-02-23 |      3 |  94.6754099868804 
 2018-02-23 |      1 |  52.4266618064681 
 2018-02-23 |      5 |  43.3877704733184 
 2018-02-23 |      2 |  23.3815439158117 
 2018-02-23 |      4 |  5.92925014836784 
 2018-02-24 |      4 |  82.3691566567076 
 2018-02-24 |      3 |    59.14386332869 
 2018-02-24 |      1 |  56.3529858789623 
 2018-02-24 |      5 |  17.7818909222602 
 2018-02-24 |      2 |  8.08320409409884 
 2018-02-25 |      1 |   51.144611434977 
 2018-02-25 |      4 |  32.6423341915492 
 2018-02-25 |      2 |  25.7686248507202 
 2018-02-25 |      3 |  3.33917220111982 
 2018-02-25 |      5 |  1.98348143815742 
 2018-02-26 |      5 |  95.2717564467113 
 2018-02-26 |      2 |  89.9541470672166 
 2018-02-26 |      4 |  73.8019448592861 
 2018-02-26 |      3 |  41.1512130216618 
 2018-02-26 |      1 |  36.3474907902939 
 2018-02-27 |      5 |  79.2906637385048 
 2018-02-27 |      4 |  62.3354455191908 
 2018-02-27 |      2 |  41.5109752476831 
 2018-02-27 |      1 |  18.9144882775624 
 2018-02-27 |      3 |   2.1427167667481 
 2018-02-28 |      4 |  85.4665146107167 
 2018-02-28 |      3 |  46.1527380247259 
 2018-02-28 |      2 |  22.3016369603851 
 2018-02-28 |      1 |    7.070596022248 
 2018-02-28 |      5 |  4.55199247079415
```

As a result of query I need to get table, that contained four columns:

1. period - A period by months and weeks = January, February, Week 1, Week 2,..., Week 9
2. gis1 - revenue by corresponding period of company Gis1
3. gis2 - the same for Gis2
4. gis3 - the same for Gis3

Here is [source files](https://drive.google.com/open?id=19_B9XA7ECvov5-cmDzDq64XE60PuU-t).
I wrote such query that creates tables in database and gives revenue by company Gis1 by weeks:

```
CREATE TABLE campaign
(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR
);
COPY campaign (id, name) FROM '/home/leonid/Campaign.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER;

CREATE TABLE app
(
  app_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR,
  campaign_id INT REFERENCES campaign (id)
);
COPY app (app_id, name, campaign_id) FROM '/home/leonid/App.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER;

CREATE TABLE revenue
(
  date DATE,
  app_id INT REFERENCES app (app_id),
  revenue DOUBLE PRECISION
);
COPY revenue (date, app_id, revenue) FROM '/home/leonid/Revenue.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER;

ALTER TABLE revenue
ADD COLUMN N SERIAL PRIMARY KEY;

SELECT DISTINCT EXTRACT (WEEK FROM r.date) AS Week, SUM (r.revenue) AS Gis1
FROM revenue r
JOIN app a ON r.app_id = a.app_id
JOIN campaign c ON a.campaign_id = c.id
WHERE c.name = 'Gis1'
GROUP BY Week
ORDER BY Week;
```

Maybe I need to use `crosstab`?

Comment: Please make this a complete question and include all relevant data directly in the question.  Links can break over time, and also readers of your question should not have to open up many new tabs in order to be able to help you.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry, I can's add images in question because of reputation = 1. But I add full code and link to a source csv files.

Comment: Post text as text, not pictures of text.

Comment: @melpomene I added link to source files.

Comment: Once more: Please post text, no links, no pictures please.

Comment: @S-Man I added tables in text.

Comment: Thanks. For the next time: Please add a _minimum_ sample. What should we do with 300(!) examples? If you want us to help you it should be your part to gives us some data that is simple the work with and that shows the whole problem. Second one: For your problem it is absolutely unnecessary to give us three tables because I believe you are able to join them by yourself. One table with all data. Now we have to join before we check your problem. Third: Please add the expected result every time.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: Not really sure if I understood your problem. But it seems that you are just want to achieve a little pivot:

---

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=7c7e48705ccec2cc8e6887b04913ebb6)

```
WITH alldata AS (                                              -- 1
    SELECT
        r.revenue,
        c.name,
        EXTRACT('isoyear' FROM date) as year,                  -- 2
        to_char(date, 'Month') as month,                       -- 3
        EXTRACT('week' FROM date) as week                      -- 4
    FROM
        revenue r
    JOIN app a ON a.app_id = r.app_id
    JOIN campaign c ON c.id = a.campaign_id
)
SELECT 
    month || ' ' || week as period,                            -- 5
    SUM(revenue) FILTER (WHERE name = 'Gis1') as gis1,         -- 7
    SUM(revenue) FILTER (WHERE name = 'Gis2') as gis2,
    SUM(revenue) FILTER (WHERE name = 'Gis3') as gis2
FROM
    alldata
GROUP BY year, month, week                                     -- 6
ORDER BY year, week
```

The result (for random extract of your too huge sample data):

```
|      period |               gis1 |               gis2 |               gis2 |
|-------------|--------------------|--------------------|--------------------|
| January   1 |  690.6488198608687 | 192.90960581696436 | 103.48598677014304 |
| January   2 |  377.6251679591726 |    85.379685234924 |   9.78507570055686 |
| January   3 |  303.6608544533801 |  121.3054939033103 |  124.4663955920365 |
| January   4 |   59.0336831992662 |   80.9564163429763 |   62.5899942406707 |
| February  5 |  123.5221801778573 |             (null) |   59.6632595622737 |
| February  6 |  368.2516021023734 |  175.3567225686088 |  182.1855864844304 |
| February  7 |  368.9193547506641 |   21.0913544631149 |  122.6141381731853 |
| February  8 | 154.03324156166846 |   81.4230771798843 |   57.7265346180577 |
| February  9 |  174.5234469014203 |   73.8019448592861 | 179.11441265601024 |
```

1. `WITH` clause calculates the whole table. Could be done within a subquery as well.
2. Calculates the year out of the date. `isoyear` instead of `year` to assure that there are no problems with the first week. `isoyear` defines exactly when the first week is (*"the first Thursday of a year is in week 1 of that year."*)
3. Get the month name
4. Get the week
5. Creating a "period" out of month name and week number
6. Grouping by the period (grouping by year and week mainly).
7. Doing the pivot using the `FILTER` clause. With that you are able to filter what you wish to aggregate. The company in your example.